# How to matchcities in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some variables related with geographical information: *City*, *Zipcode*.

I want to set values in *City* only to some certain values A or B. But in my dataset, I have other values  which belong to A.

Is there any way that I can classify different sub-values in *City* to one certain value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute force way of doing things but here it is anyway.

Since LA has zip codes in the 90000s, you could write an `ifelse` statement like below:

`data$city_new <- ifelse(data$Zipcode >= 90000, "Los Angeles", "Boston")`

But you have to be careful doing this because not all Californian zip codes are in Los Angeles (unless you are sure all the ones in your dataset are actually LA neighborhoods). The same is true of Boston.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just started to learn R. It's a fake assignment.. lol. Thank you! :)